# Expected Identifier and ARC

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am using Björn Sållarp's excellent Forward Geocoder, to be found at http://blog.sallarp.com/ipad-iphone-forward-geocoding-api-google/

However, I had to get rid of the "autorelease" in the code, since ARC does not support it. Now I have an "Expected Identifier" problem. Does anyone know how to deal with this? Here is original and the affected code:

ORIGINAL:

```
return [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, (CFStringRef)kBSGeocodingLegalCharactersToBeEscaped, kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

MY VERSION:

```
return [(NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, (CFStringRef)kGeocodingLegalCharactersToBeEscaped, kCFStringEncodingUTF8))];
```

Btw, Xcode suggested to add the "CFBridgingRelease" to the original code.

Comment: You can just ignore arc on this file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227348/nsstring-to-cfstringref-and-cfstringref-to-nsstring-in-arc/17256947#17256947

Answer (score 0):

loose the outer brackets:

```
return (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)string, NULL, (CFStringRef)kGeocodingLegalCharactersToBeEscaped, kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)kGeocodingLegalCharactersToBeEscaped, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build Phases find the classe  and in  Compiler Flgas input: -fno-objc-arc clear the project and finished