# Filter CFArray using predicates like NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter my contacts based on alphabets, something like this

```
NSArray *sectionArray = [contactAdd filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.friendListSection objectAtIndex:section]]];
```

But here the problem is contactAdd is not a regular array its CFArray defined as

```
@property  CFArrayRef contactAdd;
```

So this code wont work, is there any alternative to use the above code for CFArray or any other solution to get the desired result??

Note:I dont want to change my contactAdd to regular array, I need to use CFArray only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *array = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(self.contactAdd);
NSArray *sectionArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", [self.friendListSection objectAtIndex:section]]];
```

---

Quoting the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html) (emphasis added)

> `CFArray` is “toll-free bridged” with its Cocoa Foundation counterpart, `NSArray`. This means that the Core Foundation type is **interchangeable** in function or method calls with the bridged Foundation object. Therefore, in a method where you see an `NSArray *` parameter, you can pass in a `CFArrayRef`, and in a function where you see a `CFArrayRef` parameter, you can pass in an `NSArray` instance. This also applies to concrete subclasses of `NSArray`. See “Toll-Free Bridged Types” for more information on toll-free bridging.

Extra information about bridged casting: 
[NSString to CFStringRef and CFStringRef to NSString in ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227348/nsstring-to-cfstringref-and-cfstringref-to-nsstring-in-arc/17256947#17256947)

Comment: Its throwing error,NSLog(@"%@",array) displays (
    "<CPRecord: 0xe23ec70 ABPerson>",
    "<CPRecord: 0xe23ee70 ABPerson>",
    "<CPRecord: 0xe23f0b0 ABPerson>", so on) Error Message: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = <CPRecord: 0xe23ec70 ABPerson> rhs = z)'

Comment: Any advice, what is the reason?

Comment: My guess is that the predicate is wrong. You are using `beginswith` on an object which is not a string.