# Incompatible types casting 'NSString *' to 'CTStringRef *'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm just trying to cast NSString* to CTStringRef*

```
    NSString *foobar = @"foobar";
    CFStringRef *tmp = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef*)foobar;
```

Can someone help with this error?
"Incompatible types casting 'NSString *' to 'CTStringRef *' (aka const struct __CFString **)with a __bridge_retained cast"

I've tried with simply __bridge and it don't work either.  From the documentation, I think the _retained is the right type I need.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSString to CFStringRef and CFStringRef to NSString in ARC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227348/nsstring-to-cfstringref-and-cfstringref-to-nsstring-in-arc)

Comment: PLEASE just google your problem, is that sooo hard?

Comment: @luk2303, well it's not too hard.  I did see that other post, but the solution in that thread is not working for me.  Let me explain: I knew that removing the * would resolve the error, but a warning remains...therefore, I'm likely doing something else wrong.  Looking for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at the error message you will see what your problem is.  The hint is in this part -

> __CFString **

Notice the two * - This means that you are trying to cast to a pointer to a pointer, or in other words a reference to a reference.  `CTStringRef` is already a reference, as implied by the 'Ref' part of the name, so you don't need the * in `(__bridge_retained CFStringRef*)`

Your code should read

```
NSString *foobar = @"foobar";
CFStringRef tmp = (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)foobar;
```

Comment: You mean CFStringRef tmp, not CFStringRef *tmp.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that one :)

Comment: Removing the * fixes the error, but now a warning: 'Incompatiable pointer types initializing 'CFStringRef *' (aka 'const struct __CFStringRef **') with an expression of type CFStringRef (aka 'const struct __CFStringRef *')